# getting error cannot read file data: is a directory when making migration in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, geodjango

hi i am making an app which takes a users location and compares it with other people to find the distance. When i added a installed gdal geos postgis and proj4 i then added a pointfield from

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
```

then i did a migration and it returned an error of

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aarush/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/home/aarush/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/aarush/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/aarush/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 110, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/home/aarush/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 76, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/home/aarush/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/home/aarush/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/aarush/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/aarush/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/home/aarush/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/home/aarush/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/aarush/git_fudo/food1_back/food1_back/posts_v1/models.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager
  File "/home/aarush/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 48, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/home/aarush/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 122, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/home/aarush/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 326, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/home/aarush/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 206, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/home/aarush/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 28, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/home/aarush/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 214, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/home/aarush/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 111, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/home/aarush/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/home/aarush/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/backends/postgis/base.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .features import DatabaseFeatures
  File "/home/aarush/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/backends/postgis/features.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.db.backends.base.features import BaseSpatialFeatures
  File "/home/aarush/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/backends/base/features.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.db import models
  File "/home/aarush/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    import django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions  # NOQA
  File "/home/aarush/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/functions.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.db.models.fields import BaseSpatialField, GeometryField
  File "/home/aarush/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/fields.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis import forms, gdal
  File "/home/aarush/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/forms/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .fields import (  # NOQA
  File "/home/aarush/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/forms/fields.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal import GDALException
  File "/home/aarush/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.datasource import DataSource
  File "/home/aarush/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/datasource.py", line 39, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.driver import Driver
  File "/home/aarush/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/driver.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.prototypes import ds as vcapi, raster as rcapi
  File "/home/aarush/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/prototypes/ds.py", line 9, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.libgdal import GDAL_VERSION, lgdal
  File "/home/aarush/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/libgdal.py", line 50, in <module>
    lgdal = CDLL(lib_path)
  File "/home/aarush/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: /home/aarush/git_fudo/food1_back/food1_back: cannot read file data: Is a directory
```

to basically summarise this it is saying

```
 cannot read file data: Is a directory
```

is there something i am missing?

(if you need anymore data about my project feel free to ask!)

Comment: This may be a redundant question but did you add `'django.contrib.gis'` to the `INSTALLED_APPS` list in your settings?

Comment: @Danoram yes I did

Comment: @aarush_s Were you able to ever resolve this issue? I'm experiencing the exact same problem right now!!!